# Sound Design Journals on genre

Tags: design, sound, horror, genre, comedy

I'm looking at writing a section in a report about different genres in film, and how sound design varies for each.

Does anyone know any useful links to articles/journals/papers, preferably for Comedy, Horror and Romance.

Google seems to be useful for Horror but not the other two.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: He could be a very interesting author to study [Pierre Schaeffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Schaeffer)

Comment: Not really an answer but you could watch several films of each genre you will want to write about Then write a synopsis of each. Your results might be more detailed and grand than reading another article about the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.woodyssoundadvice.com/2011/10/13/interview-david-stone-supervising-sound-editor/

http://www.awn.com/mag/issue4.01/4.01pages/geislersound.php3

http://www.philipbrophy.com/projects/sncnm/AnimationSound.html

An interview, a first hand account, and a strange treatise on the sound and history of animation and comedy.  Go straight to the source and find the reflections that sound designers have on their own craft - there are almost as many viable theories of design as there are successful designers.

Comment: this too https://www.academia.edu/7997698/What_Do_We_Hear_The_Pluralism_of_Sound_Design_in_Hollywood_Sound_Production for more general history yet great details

Comment: This podcast has an interview with the sound designer for the series Hannibal 

http://99percentinvisible.org/episode/all-in-your-head/

-- Alan Howarth (http://alanhowarth.com/press-articles.html) is also a major sound designer for sci fi movies and a major collaborator of John Carpenter. Here's  also a short interview with him http://echoes.org/2014/02/14/alan-howarth-in-echoes-podcast/

Answer (score 0):

I've written a few essays on sound design for uni, so i feel your pain. There's not a lot of theory out there, i guess because sound design is a relatively new art form, and practitioners tend to be very pragmatic. There is, as you found, some material out there concerning the horror and thriller genres, as they're very affect driven, and sound often contributes in a very overt way. For comedy and romance, sound devices tend to be less obvious, and are far more context dependent than genre dependent, so they're not as easy to write about.

I'd recommend scoping out designingsound.org for some interviews and articles by sound designers. I'd also recommend AudioVision by Michel Chion for some interesting definitions of sound devices (it also makes for a good bibliography reference, if your report requires that).

I hope that helps!